# trying to open a php project using netbeans but error not found appears

Tags: php

I'm trying to open a PHP project using netbeans, this project was not created by me, so I move it into htdocs folder, but localhost does not recognize it and this error showed up:
(localhost worked properly when I create project myself)

[image: error image]

The location of the project is : `D:\xampp\htdocs\S21\project21`

so I tried this url: `http://localhost/s21/project21/index.php` and it did open, however without styles. It didn't load stylesheet files.

[image: unformated page]

I even edited any location inside the PHP files to the new URL but it's still not working.

any idea about why this happened? And how to fix?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put the project files directly in "D:\xampp\htdocs\" instead of in a sub folder? Also, when you say _"I even edited any location inside the php files to new url"_, what exactly do you mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: netbeans is just your IDE, it is irrelevant as to why your assets are not loading

Comment: @Mehrdad Dastgir thanks for mentioning this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your location is : `D:\xampp\htdocs\S21\project21`, so the correct URL is `http://localhost/s21/project21/index.php`.

> so I tryied this url: http://localhost/s21/project21/index.php and it did open but without style.it didnt load stylesheet files.

You need to change your asset URL :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/s21/project21/your-style.css">
<script src="http://localhost/s21/project21/your-script.js"></script>
```

---

You can still use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your-style.css">
<script src="your-script.js></script>
```

But, if you use `mod_rewrite` eg : you access to `http://localhost/s21/project21/another/endpoint`, your assets will be not found.

If you use `/style.css`, it will access to `http://localhost/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the CSS files should be relative to localhost

If you open the inspect element you will see the error of not finding the files.

Try uploading the file relative to the site as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo-bar.css">
<script src="foo-bar.js></script>
```